# stuck with system of equations coming from markov chain's stationary distribution

Tags: systems-of-equations, markov-chains

In each of the following cases determine whether the stochastic matrix P, which you may assume is irreducible, is reversible:

$ \begin{pmatrix}
0 & p & 1-p\\
1-p & 0 & p\\
p & 1-p & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$

So I am stuck with the following system of equations.

$
\pi_1p = \pi_2(1-p) \\
\pi_1(1-p) = \pi_3p \\
\pi_2p = \pi_3(1-p) \\
\pi_1 + \pi_2 + \pi_3 = 1
$

I think I used all possibilities but never my answer comes to the one provided:

$
\pi_1 = \frac{1}{1+p/(1-p) + (1-p) + p^2/(1-p)} \\
\pi_2 = \frac{p/(1-p)}{1+p/(1-p) + (1-p) + p^2/(1-p)} \\
\pi_3 = \frac{1-p+p^2/(1-p)}{1+p/(1-p) + (1-p) + p^2/(1-p)}
$

Important factor is that p could be 0 (I think...). Could someone point me to the right path so that I get the provided answer? Also when I solve it myself my solutions somehow fail to fulfill the condition that all $\pi$ should sum up to one even though I use this property to solve the equation. 
What I am doing is first I substitute one of variables say $\pi_1$ with $\pi_1 = 1 - \pi_2 - \pi_3$ in both equations where it appears and then I try to substitute one of $\pi_2$ or $\pi_3$ with other equation.
Basically I am stuck with high school math, any direction to unstuck me would be highly appreciated!

One of my attempts:

$
\pi_1p = \pi_2(1-p) \\
\pi_1(1-p) = \pi_3p \\
\pi_2p = \pi_3(1-p) \\
\pi_1 + \pi_2 + \pi_3 = 1 \\
$

$
(1-\pi_2-\pi_3)p = (1-p)\pi_2 \\
(1-\pi_2-\pi_3)(1-p) = \pi_3p \\
\pi_2p = \pi_3(1-p) \\ 
$

$
p-\pi_2p-\pi_3p = \pi_2-\pi_2p \\
1-\pi_2-\pi_3-p+\pi_2p+\pi_3p = \pi_3p \\
\pi_2p = \pi_3(1-p) \\ 
$

$
p-\pi_3p = \pi_2 \\
1-\pi_2-\pi_3-p+\pi_2p = 0 \\
\pi_2p = \pi_3(1-p) \\ 
$

$
p-\pi_3p = \pi_2 \\
1-p+\pi_2p-\pi_2-\pi_3 = 0 \\
\pi_2p = \pi_3(1-p) \\ 
$

$
p-\pi_3p = \pi_2 \\
1-p+\pi_2(p-1)-\pi_3 = 0 \\
\pi_2p = \pi_3(1-p) \\ 
$

$
p-\pi_3p = \pi_2 \\
\pi_2(p-1) = p-1+\pi_3 \\
\pi_2p = \pi_3(1-p) \\ 
$

$
(p-\pi_3p)(p-1) = p-1+\pi_3 \\
(p-\pi_3p)p = \pi_3(1-p) \\
$

$
\pi_3(1-p)-(p-\pi_3p) = p-1+\pi_3 \\
$

$
p = \frac{1}{2} \\
$

But answer remains a mystery

Comment: Show your work so that someone can point out where you’re going wrong. Are the $\pi_k$ meant to be entries of a vector?

Comment: Also, please format your mathematical expressions using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of pasting pictures of them. Your question is incomprehensible without those images and is thus inaccessible to people who depend on screen readers. Also, images are neither searchable nor do they show up in summaries.

Comment: I would suggest going back and checking that you’ve set up the system of equations correctly in the first place. The one you have here is inconsistent unless $p=1/2$. It would be helpful if you included more context for this question, such as the original problem that you’re trying to solve.

Comment: sure I will rephrase everything!

Comment: You can get displayed equations by enclosing them in double instead of single dollar signs. This is particularly relevant for legibility if you mix fractions and exponents.

Comment: I rewrote the solution from a sheet and I wanted to keep the formatting in the same form

Comment: Looks to me like the answer that you’re quoting here corresponds to some other problem: it doesn’t satisfy the detailed balance equations for the given transition matrix. As I commented originally, the system of equations that you have is consistent iff $p=1/2$, in which case $\pi_1=\pi_2=\pi_3=1/3$. Note also, that if the process is reversible, then $\mathbf\pi$ must be a stationary distribution, but by symmetry that’s clearly $\frac13(1,1,1)$, which again forces $p=1/2$ for the balance equations to be satisfied.

Comment: if you plug in $p = 1/2$ to the answer I'm quoting you get exactly that $\pi_1 = \pi_2 = \pi_3 = 1/3 $ my only problem is that I don't know how to get this parametrized solution